# Question about the practical use of super dense coding in information transmission

Tags: quantum-gate, entanglement, superdense-coding, cq-states

Question about the practical use of super dense coding in information transmission:
We know that by using super dense coding it is possible to transmit 2n classical bits transmitting n qubits, belonging to a set of 2n entangled qubits. 
Problem is, it is necessary, before starting the transmission, to deliver n qubits to Alice and n qubits to Bob, entangled together. In my opinion this fact makes super dense coding of no practical interest because normally in a transmission system the sequence of information (classical) bits is of indefinite length and consequently the length n of entangled bits given to Alice (the transmitter) should be equally of indefinite length. Which is practically very difficult!
Am I correct or am I missing something?
Thanks.